# Passing all MYSQL record into array with key and value formated

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I'm selecting from MYSQL database and I need to pass all selected records to an array in the format like this:
Array

```
(

    [1] => Weather today is rubbish
    [2] => This cake looks amazing
    [3] => His skills are mediocre
    [4] => He is very talented
    [5] => She is seemingly very agressive
    [6] => Marie was enthusiastic about the upcoming trip. Her brother was also passionate about her leaving - he would finally have the house for himself.
    [7] => To be or not to be?
)
```

I want the key to be autogenerated.and be assigned to each record.

Here us my code:

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

$SQLCommand = "SELECT fback FROM feedback";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $SQLCommand);

$i = 1; 
$query = mysqli_query($conn, 'SELECT fback FROM feedback');
$tot = mysqli_num_rows($query);
echo '<br/>You are having <b style="color:red;">' . $tot . '</b> tasks to do.<br/><br/>'; 
while($a = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
{   
     echo $i++ . '. ' . $a[0] . '<br/>';
}$featured = array();

foreach($featured as $key => $value){
  echo $a;
}
```

Comment: Why are you executing the same query twice?

Comment: So you want to have all of you results in an array with normal integers as keys (e.g. 0 for position 1, 2 for 2 etc.)?

Comment: What is the Problem with your code?

Comment: Why dont you create an array and then use it to grab your `mysqli_fetch_array`, then loop through

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean like that?

```
$featured = array();
$count = 1;
while($a = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {   
     $featured[$count] = $a[0];
     $count++; 
}

print_r($featured);
```

Comment: All I want is for all my record to be presented as array(
 1 => 'Weather today is rubbish',

Comment: You are welcome @KayBamigboye - You can Up Vote if you think its useful

Answer (score 0):

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
$i = 1; 
$query = mysqli_query($conn, 'SELECT fback FROM feedback');
$tot = mysqli_num_rows($query);
$results = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
echo '<br/>You are having <b style="color:red;">' . $tot . '</b> tasks to do.<br/><br/>'; 
$arr = []; // Your array
foreach($results as $value)
{   
    $arr[] = $value[0];
    echo $i++ . '. ' . $value[0] . '<br/>';
}
```